# Trello-like tool that lets non-logged-in users manipulate items

Tags: web-apps, project-management, hosted

I like to have a quick-and-dirty way for my team members to move cards around on a board without establishing an account, over the web. Any ideas?

I imagine the organizer needs an account, just not all the other participants.  An example of this is PlanningPoker.com, but it has a much more specific use.

Comment: Something like this? https://wekan.io/

Comment: That lets unregistered people view, but not edit.  Close, but no cigar!  Thanks very much.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark here - Planner for NextCloud with anonymous users?